# Equivalent of removing readonly from a file with TFS/MS SS in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to make Mercurial treat a file as if it matches the source control copy even if it has been altered? This was an easy trick to do with Team Foundation Server / Source Safe where just making the file writable through explorer would make those systems ignore that file on check ins.

(Note this is a file that is checked in and has a value but is sometimes different per developer, think connection strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define aliases in your [hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) for the commit command that excludes the file you don't want to track in the commit.

```
[alias]
xcommit=commit --exclude path/to/file
xstatus=status --exclude path/to/file
```

The hgrc reference says that you can define aliases with the same name as existing commands; I found that it worked for `hg status` but not for `hg commit`.

I found that .hgignore doesn't obey entries for files that are already in the repository so that's not an option.

Comment: Doesn't forget remove the file entirely from version control that on the next push it will be gone from the repo unless you pull a previous change set?

Comment: @Chris: you're right.  I had multiple test repositories and looked in the wrong one to see if my suggestion worked. :(  Changed my answer.

Comment: Interesting solution, but fairly high on the PITA level to manage.